# creating a character width agnostic function

Tags: c++

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++03 application where I would like to have a single function perform string operations with different parameters depending on the type of string passed in.

For example, if I wanted to (naively) find the path portion of a file name with something like this:

```
template< typename Elem, typename Traits, typename Alloc >
std::basic_string< Elem, Traits, Alloc > GetFilePath( 
    const std::basic_string< Elem, Traits, Alloc >& filename )
{
    std::basic_string< Elem, Traits, Alloc >::size_type slash = 
        filename.find_last_of( "\\/" ) + 1;
    return filename.substr( 0, slash );
}
```

for wchar_t based strings, it would use `L"\\/"` and for char based strings `"\\/"`.

And the calling convention would be something like this:

```
std::wstring pathW = GetFilePath( L"/Foo/Bar/Baz.txt" );

std::string pathA = GetFilePath( "/Foo/Bar/Baz.txt" );
```

Can anybody suggest how to modify the above function for this goal? (Yes, I realize I could have two functions that overload the `GetFilePath` name. I would like to avoid that, if possible.)

Comment: Have you considered just overloading for the existing typedefs of `std::string` and `std::wstring`? Alternately add dependent parameters to your function such as the path and token ... ok final edit Boost has a pretty awesome filesystem namespace as well as string algorithms.

Comment: The problem with your method is that, even if you get it character width agnostic, it will *not* be encoding-agnostic. So I’m not sure what you’ve gained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a traits class for the path separator and whatever else you're interested in:

```
template<typename Elem> struct PathTraits { static const Elem *separator; };
template<> const char *PathTraits<char>::separator = "\\/";
template<> const wchar_t *PathTraits<wchar_t>::separator = L"\\/";
```

Then in your function template you can use `find_last_of(PathTraits<Elem>::separator)`.

Comment: `static` … + out-of-line initialisation.